# AppleScript Wi-Fi connector

Tags: applescript

I have been trying to explore AppleScript a bit by writing a few simple lines of code. I have tried writing a small bit that would allow me to access the list of Wi-Fi's available, and input the password to said Wi-Fi.

So far I have gotten to the point where it recognizes the Wi-Fi's available, but does not allow me to make the Wi-Fi into a type string. I have written the code for selecting the Wi-Fi from a list, but I cannot figure out how to make the Wi-Fi's into a list.

Would anyone be able to help me figure this out?

```
display dialog "Wifi Selector © Afnaan Qureshi"
set main to display dialog " ." buttons {"Quit", "Enter Password"}
if main = {button returned:"Enter Password"} or trueaftermain = "1" then


    set results to paragraphs 2 thru -1 of (do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s | sed -nE 's/[ ]*(.*) [a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:.+/\\1/p'")
    set my_list to results
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
    set list_2_string to my_list as text
    set main to display dialog my_list
    set wpass to choose from list {my_list} with title "Pick The Wifi" with prompt "Choose WPA2" OK button name "Choose" cancel button name "Cancel" default items {"quit"}
end if
```

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when seeking to debug code that's not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is too complicated.

`results` is already the list you are expecting.

```
set results to paragraphs of (do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s | sed -nE 's/[ ]*(.*) [a-z0-9]{2}:[a-z0-9]{2}:.+/\\1/p'")
set wpass to choose from list results with title "Pick The Wifi" with prompt "Choose WPA2" OK button name "Choose"
```

Be aware that `wpass` is also a list, or `false` if the user presses <kbd>Cancel</kbd>

And if you are using `text item delimiters` make sure to reset the delimiters later to avoid unexpected behavior.